# Use spinner-based time picker on new Android app?

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design, timepicker

I'm developing an Android app which has target API for Android 6. As you may know, in Android 5 they introduced Material look and feel, and included the Calendar Date picker and Analog Clock time picker.

The Android 4 time pickers had individual spinners for Month/Day/Year and Hour/Minute/AM-PM. I think that they are quicker to use, especially the time picker.

How can I use those older date and time picker dialogs while still keeping the Android 5-6 overall look and feel for the other activities in the app?

I know that those older pickers are probably only kept for compatibility, but would still like to use them anyway. (I'm assuming that packaging them into the app would be more difficult.)

For reference, this is the code I am currently using.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
...
    new DatePickerDialog(this, callback, y, m, d).show();
```

Comment: How about setting theme as the 2nd parameter and onDateListener `new DatePickerDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen,listener, y, m, d); `

Comment: Thank you! This worked. If this were an answer I'd upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting theme as the 2nd parameter and onDateListener

```
new DatePickerDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen,listener, y, m, d);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Thanks to @Dhina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190233/use-spinner-based-time-picker-on-new-android-app#35203223) for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up creating a custom style, because when I used the Holo Dialog style (instead of Full Screen as originally suggested) I got sort of a window within a window. This is what I ended up using for the desired net effect:

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyPickerDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

`MyActivity.java`:

```
new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.MyPickerDialogTheme, callback, y, m, d).show();
```